# I can `require_once __DIR__.'/folder.file.php';` on PHP file, but am unable to get the variable. Why would that ever happen?

Tags: php

Both `current_file.php` and `req_file.php` are in the same directory and I'm able to `require_once __DIR__.'/req_file.php'` within `current_file.php`. I've even tested `file_exists(__DIR__.'/req_file.php')` and it does. `req_file.php` has `<?php $test = 'yup'; ?>` on it and that is all. For some reason the `isset($test)` is false. I've never seen this behavior and even use a similar technique to include my database connection. Why would `!isset($test)` be true?

Comment: In which file do you check for `$test`?

Comment: In `current_file.php` after I do the `require_once` from the other page.

Comment: Maybe someone can clear this up for me... Why not just `require_once('req_file.php')` if they are in the same directory?

Comment: I tried that too, without the parentheses.

Comment: PHP will search for files in the `include_path` config first. Using a file in the same directory should have `./filename.php`.

Comment: Try to use `require` instead of `require_once`. As the name says - `require_once` will require this file only once. So maybe this file was required before, so it's not included again here, so you have no access to these variables.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, what's the difference between `'./filename.php'`, `__DIR__.'/filename.php'`, and `'filename.php'` using `require_once`?

Comment: Context is lost here. What is between `require` and `isset` check? No codelines? I won't believe it.

Comment: @StackSlave `./` is relative to the current path, `__DIR__` is absolute and a created path by PHP.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, I would think `__DIR__` is just fine then. Why wouldn't it work? The file is showing that it exists. I just cannot access my variable.

Comment: As @u_mulder said, your description needs to be updated with some details. Please quote your file contents. I did not want to discuss the include path, I've just explained because it was asked.

Comment: None of the above comments helped, but thanks for trying.